# Notepad++ regex find/replace adjacent ids

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
ID, term, functional category
GO:0008166,viral replication,P,
GO:0008167,sigma virus replication,P,
GO:0008168,GO:0004480,methyltransferase activity,F,
GO:0008169,C-methyltransferase activity,F,
```

I just need to use `notepad++` to move IDs to their own row and copy what was in that same row to the bottom. So ideally the final output would look like:

```
ID, term, functional category
GO:0008166,viral replication,P,
GO:0008167,sigma virus replication,P,
GO:0008168,,methyltransferase activity,F,
GO:0004480,methyltransferase activity,F,
GO:0008169,C-methyltransferase activity,F,
```

I tried using the replace function, finding instances of IDs right next to each other using: `(\w+:\d+),(\w+:\d+),(.*),[A-Z]` and replacing with `$1,$3,$4\r$2,$3,$4`.

However, every time I try and "find" these instances in `notepad++` it'll hi-light the entire list and the command will not work.

I'm not very experienced with this, so if somebody can help me I'd appreciate it! Thank you!

original file: http://www.geneontology.org/doc/GO.terms_alt_ids

I got rid of header and turned it into a csv by replacing all tabs with a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find / Replace Repeated IDs in CSV

The not-entirely-optimised-but-functional regex I used was:

```
(GO:[\d]+),(GO:[\d]+)(.*)
```

replacing with:

```
$1$3\n$2$3
```

Giving the output:

```
ID, term, functional category
GO:0008166,viral replication,P,
GO:0008167,sigma virus replication,P,
GO:0008168,methyltransferase activity,F,
GO:0004480,methyltransferase activity,F,
GO:0008169,C-methyltransferase activity,F,
```

Note that this **doesn't** duplicate the comma in your desired output as I thought that might be a side effect, rather than desired.

If the duplicated comma is desired, use:

```
$1,$3\n$2$3
```

as the replacement instead.

### Explanation

`(GO:[\d]+)` - 1st capturing group, match literal "GO:" followed by one or more digits (`$1`)

`,` - match literal comma (used to detect repeated IDs / ignore non-repeated ones)

`(GO:[\d]+)` - 2nd capturing group, same as first! (`$2`)

`(.*)` - 3rd capturing group, match 0 or more of "anything" - shorthand for "rest of the line" here (`$3`)

`$1$3\n$2$3` - print id `1` followed by rest of line; then a newline; print id `2` followed by rest of line

### Caveat

Be advised that for the above regular expression to work you must have the search option `. matches newline` disabled. Otherwise, the 3rd capturing group will match too much.

[image: dot matches newline]

Comment: Thank you! I feel like I was close, I've been learning this text editing slowly and I hit problems all the time. Have a good day

Comment: My pleasure, good luck, and you too :) PS [regex101](http://regex101.com) is your friend for these sorts of things!

Comment: I hate doing this, although I did just award the right answer. I didn't realize it but this function is copying everything under the instances of the duplicate IDs and pasting it over and over again. Is there a way to make the (.*) end at a single row?

Comment: @kevluv93 Add a `$` to the end of the find section to make it terminate at EoL (which it did in my testing, but obviously real testing > small sample data!) ie `(GO:[\d]+),(GO:[\d]+)(.*)$`. You could also prepend with `^` to match start-of-line for completeness: `^(GO:[\d]+),(GO:[\d]+)(.*)$`

Comment: I still can't seem to get this command to work. It's still selecting every data point under the instances of duplicate IDs.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to use chat yet, original file is here: [link] (http://www.geneontology.org/doc/GO.terms_alt_ids) I made it csv, and got rid of header.

Comment: Super User, y u no be helpful? There's no link in your comment, presumably you need rep for that too. Can you edit the question to include it?

Comment: @kevluv93 Operating on the tsv directly (change `,` to `\t`) seems to work here also :S

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26854/discussion-on-answer-by-bertieb-notepad-regex-find-replace-adjacent-ids).

Comment: @kevluv93 Hopefully [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26854/discussion-on-answer-by-bertieb-notepad-regex-find-replace-adjacent-ids) room has the right access for you to talk in.